# How import the csv file into database using APIView

Tags: database, django-rest-framework, csv-import

How can I import the `csv` file data to the database using the `APIView` in rest `django`

Answer (score 0):

You can use xl2dict ([https://pypi.org/project/xl2dict/](https://https:pypi.org/project/xl2dict/)) which converts spreadsheets in to python dictionary.

$ pip install xl2dict

Then You can easily update your database using,

from xl2dict import XlToDict

obj= XlToDict()

obj.convert_sheet_to_dict(file_path=, sheet=,
filter_variables_dict={"User Type" : "Admin", "Environment" : "Dev"})

### Updating the database

Model.objects.update_or_create(**obj)

You can use the above method for updating database.

Alternate method is to use **python pandas.**